# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown> (ListView Maybe?)

Tags: java, android

I made an app, it works well in virtual device and real device, but today my app is throwing exceptions, maybe it is the same with some old errors in here, but I can not find my own answer for this. So, please tell me how to solve it, thanks so much

here is my logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gvc.tvschedule, PID: 1918
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
... 48 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f0b0068}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:806)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:618)
... 51
```

here under is Layout XML: getprogram_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutProgram"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutProgram"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

    <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
     </ListView>

    <!-- @android:id/list or @id/android:list  -->
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and: view_program_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/programtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="6sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/programtitle"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:drawableLeft="@+id/programtime" />
       <!-- android:background="@color/blue2" -->

</LinearLayout>
```

and Java : ProgramPickerActivity.java

```
package com.gvc.tvschedule;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.gvc.service.DBController;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProgramPickerActivity extends Activity {

    // DB Class to perform DB related operations
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    // Progress Dialog Object
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    HashMap<String, String> queryValues;
    private static String titleTextFromView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getprogram_main);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> programList = controller.generalProgram(MainActivity.getNameOfChannel(), DatePickerActivity.getDate());


        if (programList.size() != 0) {
            // Set the User Array list in ListView

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), programList, R.layout.view_program_entry, new String[] {
                            "ptime", "ptitle" }, new int[] { R.id.programtime, R.id.programtitle });
            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView titleVIew = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.programtitle);
                    titleTextFromView = titleVIew.getText().toString();

                    createPopupWindownForDescription(titleTextFromView);
                }
            });

        }

         prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         prgDialog.setMessage("loading...");
         prgDialog.setCancelable(false);



    }




    private void createPopupWindownForDescription(String pTitle){
        String content = controller.getDescription(pTitle);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProgramPickerActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Content");
        builder.setMessage(content);

        builder.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if(prgDialog!=null)
            prgDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public static String getTitleTextFromView(){
        return titleTextFromView;
    }


}
```

I think the trouble is related with the listview, because, when no data put on listview, it is fine, but with data, it threw the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current problem is

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/programtitle"
       ...
       android:drawableLeft="@+id/programtime" />  // HERE
```

You are referencing the other `TextView` but you should be referencing a `Drawable`. My guess is that you want to put it to the left of the other `TextView`?

If this is the case, the `LinearLayout` will lay them out from left to right by default so you just need to put them in the order that you want them to appear. Also, not a problem but since they are left to right by default, there's no need for

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

It's not showing when you don't have any items in your `ListView` because the layout is never inflated so the error is never caught.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft)

Comment: I love you so much, you save my 2 days. It works like a charm

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be a `+` before `id` if you're referencing an existing id

Answer (score 1):

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

use that, you're welcome

PS: Change

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

for:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: change the name... "list" is way to generic. Use "list_items" or something like that

Comment: also, remove: android:drawableLeft="@+id/programtime" the horizontal linearlayout should be more than enough